# jQuery gives error in the table

Tags: jquery

I'm getting errors when I add the td tag.

CSS

```
.group {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd
}
```

JS

```
$('.color').on('change', '.selectMe', function () {
    var group = $(this).closest("div").siblings(".group");
    var indis = $(':selected', this).index();
    if (indis > 0) {
        indis -= 1;
        group.hide().filter(':eq(' + indis + ')').fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        group.hide();
    }
});
```

it's works
HTML

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="5"id="myTable">
<tr>
<div class="color">            
<select name="a" class="selectMe">
<option value="" selected></option>
<option value="1">Message</option>
<option value="2">Not Message</option>
</select>
</div>
</tr> 
<tr>
<div class="group">Message</div>
</tr>
</table>
```

not works

HTML

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="5"id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="color">            
<select name="a" class="selectMe">
<option value="" selected></option>
<option value="1">Message</option>
<option value="2">Not Message</option>
</select>
</div>
</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td>
<div class="group">Message</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

message I am getting when I use the td tag. table gives an error when I use it in.

I want to give message in the table. How do we do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NkLwL/1/)

**JQuery**

```
$('.selectMe').on('change', function () {

    var group = $(this).closest("tr").next().find('div'); // group will be assigned the <div> in the second <tr>
    var indis = $(':selected', this).index();
    if (indis > 0) {
        indis -= 1;
        group.hide().filter(':eq(' + indis + ')').fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        group.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: perfect. http://jsfiddle.net/ahmetsadri/zyLxm/  In this way I show different messages in 2 cells

Answer (score 0):

If you see the DOM structure of new HTML, then the `group` is not a `sibling` any more (which you were using at `var group = $(this).closest("div").siblings(".group");`, so you'll have to modify your jQuery code accordingly, like the one Amir has provided.

Comment: This would have suited being a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is: Why are you in nowadays use tables? 
Second solution?

```
$("#selectMe").on('change', function(e){
    var value=$(this).val();
    if($.trim(value)!="")
        $("#group").fadeIn(300).html(value);
    else
        $("#group").html("").hide();
    return false;
});
```

HTML for this:

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="5"id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="color">            
<select name="a" class="selectMe">
<option value="" selected>Select something...</option>
<option value="Message">Message</option>
<option value="Not Message">Not Message</option>
</select>
</div>
</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td>
<div class="group">Message</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is help You?

Answer (score 0):

perfect. In this way I show different messages in 2 cells [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmetsadri/zyLxm)

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="5"id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="color">            
                <select name="a" class="selectMe">

                    <option value="1"></option>
                    <option value="2"> Message</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
    <td>
        Message 2
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="group">Message</div>
        </td>
        <td>
              <div class="group">Message 2</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```